# ggplot2 histogram/bar chart with date and time

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, histogram, bar-chart

Given this `df`:

```
       Date     Time     Values 
1 2018-04-02 09:15:00 14.00000
2 2018-04-02 09:30:00  4.00000
3 2018-04-02 09:45:00 20.00000
4 2018-04-02 10:00:00 30.00000
5 2018-04-02 10:15:00 14.00000
6 2018-04-02 10:30:00 31.16667
```

I'm trying to do a histogram/bar chart ordered by `Values`, while the X axis values are `Date` or `Time` (two different charts). This is the example with `Time` chart:

```
ggplot(df, aes(reorder(Time, Values)), y=Values) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

I have been trying with `geom_col` and `geom_bar` with stat="identity" and other cases, but nothing seems to work for both charts. For the code above it appears this error:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Comment: Please paste the output of `dput` on your data. This seems like a situation where it's important to see the exact value types in your data

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with var type (`Date`, `factor`, `POSIXct`):

```
my_text <- ' Date     Time     Values 
1 2018-04-02 09:15:00 14.00000
2 2018-04-02 09:30:00  4.00000
3 2018-04-02 09:45:00 20.00000
4 2018-04-02 10:00:00 30.00000
5 2018-04-02 10:15:00 14.00000
6 2018-04-02 10:30:00 31.16667'

df <- read.table(text = my_text)
str(df) # factors ...

df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date))
df$Time <- as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(df$Date), as.character(df$Time)))

str(df) # Date and POSIXct 
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(reorder(Time, Values), y = Values)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]